# show that $ \sum_{pq \leq x} \frac{\log p \log q}{pq (\log p + \log q)} = \log x + O(\log \log x) $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I've been reading through Atle Selberg's "Elementary" proof of the [Prime Number Theorem](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~mahlburg/teaching/handouts/2014-7230/Selberg-ElemPNT1949.pdf).  That seems to be an ironic usage of the word.  A lot of discussions focus on the Selberg formula:

$$ \theta(x) \;\log x + \sum_{p \leq x} \log p \; \theta\big(\frac{x}{p}\big) = 2x \log x + O(x) $$

The left side is almost suggesting to let $p=1$ be a prime number.  Here $\theta$ is the sum of logs of primes:

$$ \theta(x) = \sum_{p \leq x} \log p = \log \bigg[ \prod_{p \leq x} p \bigg]$$
Here emphasizing the [product of all prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) (rather than a factorial), which can be used to prove the [infinitude of primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem).  We can write as correlations of the sequence $\{ \log p: p \text{ prime}\}$.

$$ \sum_{pq \leq x} \log p \, \log q + \sum_{p \leq x} \log^2 p = 2x \log x + O(x)  $$

---

Let me go back a few steps and go through three steps in Selberg's derivation.

$$ \sum_{p \leq x} \log p = x\log x + O(x) \tag{A} $$

This step easily implies

$$ \sum_{pq \leq x} \frac{\log p \log q}{pq} = \frac{1}{2} \log^2 x + O(\log x)  \tag{B}$$

and then we can do a partial summation to get :

$$ \sum_{pq \leq x} \frac{\log p \log q}{pq (\log p + \log q)} =  \log x + O(\log \log x)   \tag{C}$$

In fact I do not see at all how (A) → (B) → (C)

---

I simply do not have the facility to do all the re-arrangments he talks about.  Here is [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts):

$$ \sum_{k=m}^n f_k \Delta g_k = [f_{n+1}g_{n+1}-f_mg_m]-\sum_{k=m}^n g_{k+1}f_k $$

Answer (score 0):

Summation by parts is not the same as partial summation, usually he refers to Abel's summation formula, namely that
$$\sum_{y<n\leq x}a(n)f(n)=A(x)f(x)-A(y)f(y)-\int_y^xA(t)f'(t)dt$$
where $f$ is differentiable on $[y,x]$ and $A(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}a(n)$ with $A(x)=0$ for $x<1$.